# Macro to Modify Content Control Properties for Directory of Documents

Tags: vba, module, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I have over 300 documents with a table coverpage, within one of the cells is a content control box with incorrect properties (the title and the tag are both named wrong).  I can so far create a macro to fix the properties but only after I click into the cell by opening each document one by one.  Is there a way to run a macro that can find this content control box in a table and amend the properties and save?

Comment: Please add some code so we can help you fix your problem!

Answer (score 0):

To search for a Content Control with a certain Title and/or Tag in a document and then change the Title or Tag, you'd use code something like this ...

```
Dim cc As ContentControl
For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If cc.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        If cc.Tag = "InErrorTag" And cc.Title = "InErrorTitle" Then
            'then correct the Tag and Title
            cc.Tag = "CorrectedTag"
            cc.Title = "CorrectedTitle"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

To then perform this replacement in a batch process of updating multiple documents you need additional code.

There is a Wiki article [Batch Editing MS Word Documents](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom-mso_2016/batch-editing-ms-word-documents-file-handling/fe2ddc73-fe11-4200-bc58-cdc67c9ce915) that provides cross platform (Windows and Mac) VBA code for that purpose. You can merge the article's code with the Content Control replacement code above to accomplish you task.