# Changing the content of multiple ContentControls at once

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I have a document with a ContentControl containing a dropdown list of six items, that is duplicated many times through one document.

I want to replace the list items.

Each value of the list stays at the same position and should stay selected as before; they should just get a new name (e.g. changing values A-F into 1-6; everywhere I selected D, should now be selected 4)

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923808/macro-to-modify-content-control-properties-for-directory-of-documents/51949604#51949604) but it's not executable. I pasted this into a new module.

It doesn't have to be a VBA approach, I'd be fine with a find&replace method  or other built-in tool.
It can be a VBA approach, if there is not much understanding/editing needed on my side.

This is my list:
[image]

I am not able to set a value that differs from the name, they are always the same. When I type in one, the other is typed simultaneously.

Comment: Where did  you paste the code?

Comment: You need to mention what type your content controls are. Such a control does  not have a `name` property. Are you referring to its `Title` property? It is a container for specific types of content...  They may contain text, dates, lists, Dropdown List, paragraphs, tables etc. **So, what type they are and what property do you need to change**? Their `Range.Text`, their `Title` or what? What to `Find` in order to `Replace`?

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I edited my question accordingly

Comment: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38464-combo-box-content-control-how-update-list.html

Comment: You don't need VBA to do this. See Greg Maxey's article about mapped content controls: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/mapped_content_controls.html

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** - fixed the issue with re-setting the value after mapping the list to the new values.

Here's something for you to work with:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    
    For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        If cc.Type = wdContentControlDropdownList Then
            UpdateListItems cc
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub UpdateListItems(cc As ContentControl)
    Dim le As ContentControlListEntry, currVal, newVal, rngVal, txt
    Dim sel As ContentControlListEntry
    currVal = cc.Range.Text
    Debug.Print "---------------------------------"
    Debug.Print "Control", cc.Title, "Current='" & currVal & "'"
    For Each le In cc.DropdownListEntries
        txt = le.Text
        If txt <> cc.PlaceholderText.Value Then   'ignore placeholder text
            newVal = MapListValue(txt)            'get the new list entry value
            Debug.Print txt, le.Value, newVal
            If currVal = txt Then Set sel = le    'remember which was selected, if any
            le.Text = newVal                      'you may not need to set both?
            le.Value = newVal
        End If
    Next le
    If Not sel Is Nothing Then sel.Select 're-select any selected option
End Sub


'Map a list entry to a new value: return original value if no mapping
Function MapListValue(v)
    Select Case v
        Case "OriginalValue_1": MapListValue = "NewValue_1"
        Case "OriginalValue_2": MapListValue = "NewValue_2"
        Case "OriginalValue_3": MapListValue = "NewValue_3"
        Case "OriginalValue_4": MapListValue = "NewValue_4"
        Case "OriginalValue_5": MapListValue = "NewValue_5"
        Case Else: MapListValue = v 'just return original value
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach. I'm not sure I understand everything correctly. I can make it a running macro, but I get a runtime error 6215, telling me that there are values with the same name.
I changed the characters A-E in the lower list of the macro to my new values. Do I have to edit anything else? As I said, my kowledge in vba is very low.

Comment: I used the example values you gave: "A" maps to "1", "B" maps to "2" etc etc.   I don't have your document to test with.

Comment: Sure, but is it sufficient to only replace A-E with the texts I need? Do I need to mark a certain portion of text? only the cc boxes? There are other cc boxes that should stay the same, can they be inside the marking without being changed? I sadly can't provide a sample as it's a company document...

Comment: In MapListValue, the cases are the changes you want to see made, i.e. if you want "Cookie" to be changed to "Dough", you'd for example change `Case "A": MapListValue = 1` to "Case "Cookie": MapListValue = "Dough". As for the exceptions ,you could catch those with a different function that checks whether the cc.Name is in the list of exceptions and then adjust it to something like `If cc.Type = wdContentControlDropdownList And Not isAnException(cc.Name) Then` *if* you know the names of the exception controls ofc.

Comment: Made some edits above which hopefully clarify the mapping process a little.  How would the CC drop-downs which should be left alone be identified?  Do they have different list items or ???   I don't care about anything in the document other than the CC controls, so you could always delete everything else...